# changing header color on blogspot via html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I have a new [website](http://jackandjunk.blogspot.my/)

and i used some template online and did some modification.
However I am unable to change the grayish color on the sub header on the upper left, which is called "More than just junk" I wanna change it to white. Any help?

Also, when u navigate to the menu on the top right, you can see a drop down menu. I created a 'About Me' page but the top half seems to be whitish and not displaying properly. If it was unable to display the main page sliding pictures then I don't mind to remove it on this page. Any help?

The template I used is from [here](https://gooyaabitemplates.com/memento-creative-blogger-template/)

Thanks

Comment: Instead of letting us find the code of the template you're using, why don't you find it the pieces that renders it and post it here in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Alter your stylesheet. Find `.Header .description` in your theme's stylesheet.

```
.Header .description {
    margin: .5em 0 10px;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

to this, adding the `color` property.

```
.Header .description {
    margin: .5em 0 10px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    color: #fff;
}
```